# Problems with backtest.plottrades() function from TradingWithPython

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to recreate the `iPython` notebook from the Trading With Python website found here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11352905/notebooks/twp_302b_backtesting.ipynb

but when I run the **`bt.plotTrades()`** function, I get the following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-1006defd22d1> in <module>()
----> 1 bt.plotTrades() # plot price and trades (short=red markers, long=green markers)
      2 
      3 figure()
      4 bt.pnl.plot(style='x-') # plot pnl
      5 title('pnl')

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tradingWithPython/lib/backtest.py in plotTrades(self)
    137 
    138         p = self.data['price']
--> 139         p.plot(style='x-')
    140 
    141         # ---plot markers

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in __call__(self, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   3495                            colormap=colormap, table=table, yerr=yerr,
   3496                            xerr=xerr, label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 3497                            **kwds)
   3498     __call__.__doc__ = plot_series.__doc__
   3499 

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in plot_series(data, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   2585                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   2586                  label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2587                  **kwds)
   2588 
   2589 

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   2382         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   2383 
-> 2384     plot_obj.generate()
   2385     plot_obj.draw()
   2386     return plot_obj.result

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in generate(self)
    985         self._compute_plot_data()
    986         self._setup_subplots()
--> 987         self._make_plot()
    988         self._add_table()
    989         self._make_legend()

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _make_plot(self)
   1662                              stacking_id=stacking_id,
   1663                              is_errorbar=is_errorbar,
-> 1664                              **kwds)
   1665             self._add_legend_handle(newlines[0], label, index=i)
   1666 

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _plot(cls, ax, x, y, style, column_num, stacking_id, **kwds)
   1676             cls._initialize_stacker(ax, stacking_id, len(y))
   1677         y_values = cls._get_stacked_values(ax, stacking_id, y, kwds['label'])
-> 1678         lines = MPLPlot._plot(ax, x, y_values, style=style, **kwds)
   1679         cls._update_stacker(ax, stacking_id, y)
   1680         return lines

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _plot(cls, ax, x, y, style, is_errorbar, **kwds)
   1298             else:
   1299                 args = (x, y)
-> 1300             return ax.plot(*args, **kwds)
   1301 
   1302     def _get_index_name(self):

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1809                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1810                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1811             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1812         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1813         if pre_doc is None:

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1425             kwargs['color'] = c
   1426 
-> 1427         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   1428             self.add_line(line)
   1429             lines.append(line)

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    384                 return
    385             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 386                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    387                     yield seg
    388                 return

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    372         ncx, ncy = x.shape[1], y.shape[1]
    373         for j in xrange(max(ncx, ncy)):
--> 374             seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
    375             ret.append(seg)
    376         return ret

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _makeline(self, x, y, kw, kwargs)
    278         default_dict = self._getdefaults(None, kw, kwargs)
    279         self._setdefaults(default_dict, kw, kwargs)
--> 280         seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
    281         self.set_lineprops(seg, **kwargs)
    282         return seg

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py in __init__(self, xdata, ydata, linewidth, linestyle, color, marker, markersize, markeredgewidth, markeredgecolor, markerfacecolor, markerfacecoloralt, fillstyle, antialiased, dash_capstyle, solid_capstyle, dash_joinstyle, solid_joinstyle, pickradius, drawstyle, markevery, **kwargs)
    364         # update kwargs before updating data to give the caller a
    365         # chance to init axes (and hence unit support)
--> 366         self.update(kwargs)
    367         self.pickradius = pickradius
    368         self.ind_offset = 0

/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in update(self, props)
    854                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
    855                 if func is None or not six.callable(func):
--> 856                     raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
    857                 func(v)
    858             changed = True

AttributeError: Unknown property color_cycle
```

my code from my `iPython` notebook is as follows, and the **`bt.data()`** and **`bt.sharpe`** yield the exact same results as that of the example notebook :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tradingWithPython as twp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

%matplotlib inline                                   # Enable inline plotting
np.__version__, pd.__version__, twp.__version__

price = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])             # arange() not working??
signal = pd.Series(index=price.index)

signal[2] = 100
signal[3] = 0
signal[6] = -100
signal[8] = 0

bt = twp.Backtest(price,signal)
bt.data['delta'] = bt.data['shares'].diff().fillna(0)
bt.data
bt.sharpe

bt.plotTrades()                                      # plot price and trades
figure()
bt.pnl.plot(style='x-')                              # plot pnl
title('pnl')
print ("Sharpe: ", bt.sharpe)
```

What does the **`AttributError`** mean and how can I resolve it to recreate the results found in the example notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure where this error comes from, but it is annoying for sure.
This is how to fix it:

open **init**.py of the tradingWithPython library  and comment out line 9:

`#pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'  # make nicer plots`

This should take care of it.

**Update:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995707/attributeerror-unknown-property-color-cycle) is more on the issue and its fix.

Comment: Thanks jev for coming back so quickly with the solution! That did the trick.