# Pandas 0.19: Attribute error "unknown property color_cycle" still exists while performing boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, attributeerror

Unlike what has been said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995707/attributeerror-unknown-property-color-cycle), the `AttributeError: Unknown property color_cycle` is still persistent in the newest Pandas version (`0.19.0-1`).

In my case, I have a dataframe similar to this, although much longer (3,000,000 rows):

```
     A         B    C
1    05010001  17   1
2    05020001  5    1
3    05020002  11   1
4    05020003  2    1
5    05030001  86   1
6    07030001  84   2
7    07030002  10   2
8    08010001  16   3
```

For some reason, if I implement this very example, there are no errors. In my actual case, executing the simple

`df.boxplot(by='C')`

triggers this mess:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-5c645348f82f> in <module>()
----> 1 df.boxplot(by='C')

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in boxplot(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
   5514 
   5515         columns = list(data.dtype.names)
-> 5516         arrays = [data[k] for k in columns]
   5517         return arrays, columns
   5518     else:

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in boxplot(data, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
   2687     ax : Matplotlib axes object, optional
   2688     fontsize : int or string
-> 2689     rot : label rotation angle
   2690     figsize : A tuple (width, height) in inches
   2691     grid : Setting this to True will show the grid

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in _grouped_plot_by_column(plotf, data, columns, by, numeric_only, grid, figsize, ax, layout, return_type, **kwargs)
   3091     >>> df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCD'), index=index)
   3092     >>>
-> 3093     >>> grouped = df.groupby(level='lvl1')
   3094     >>> boxplot_frame_groupby(grouped)
   3095     >>>

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.pyc in plot_group(keys, values, ax)
   2659     create a figure with the default figsize, causing the figsize=parameter to
   2660     be ignored.
-> 2661     """
   2662     if ax is None and len(plt.get_fignums()) > 0:
   2663         ax = _gca()

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1810                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1811                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1812             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1813         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1814         if pre_doc is None:

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.pyc in boxplot(self, x, notch, sym, vert, whis, positions, widths, patch_artist, bootstrap, usermedians, conf_intervals, meanline, showmeans, showcaps, showbox, showfliers, boxprops, labels, flierprops, medianprops, meanprops, capprops, whiskerprops, manage_xticks)
   3321                            meanline=meanline, showfliers=showfliers,
   3322                            capprops=capprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops,
-> 3323                            manage_xticks=manage_xticks)
   3324         return artists
   3325 

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.pyc in bxp(self, bxpstats, positions, widths, vert, patch_artist, shownotches, showmeans, showcaps, showbox, showfliers, boxprops, whiskerprops, flierprops, medianprops, capprops, meanprops, meanline, manage_xticks)
   3650                     boxes.extend(dopatch(box_x, box_y, **final_boxprops))
   3651                 else:
-> 3652                     boxes.extend(doplot(box_x, box_y, **final_boxprops))
   3653 
   3654             # draw the whiskers

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.pyc in doplot(*args, **kwargs)
   3564         if vert:
   3565             def doplot(*args, **kwargs):
-> 3566                 return self.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3567 
   3568             def dopatch(xs, ys, **kwargs):

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1810                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1811                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1812             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1813         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1814         if pre_doc is None:

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.pyc in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1422             kwargs['color'] = c
   1423 
-> 1424         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   1425             self.add_line(line)
   1426             lines.append(line)

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.pyc in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    384                 return
    385             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 386                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    387                     yield seg
    388                 return

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.pyc in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    372         ncx, ncy = x.shape[1], y.shape[1]
    373         for j in xrange(max(ncx, ncy)):
--> 374             seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
    375             ret.append(seg)
    376         return ret

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.pyc in _makeline(self, x, y, kw, kwargs)
    278         default_dict = self._getdefaults(None, kw, kwargs)
    279         self._setdefaults(default_dict, kw, kwargs)
--> 280         seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
    281         self.set_lineprops(seg, **kwargs)
    282         return seg

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.pyc in __init__(self, xdata, ydata, linewidth, linestyle, color, marker, markersize, markeredgewidth, markeredgecolor, markerfacecolor, markerfacecoloralt, fillstyle, antialiased, dash_capstyle, solid_capstyle, dash_joinstyle, solid_joinstyle, pickradius, drawstyle, markevery, **kwargs)
    365         # update kwargs before updating data to give the caller a
    366         # chance to init axes (and hence unit support)
--> 367         self.update(kwargs)
    368         self.pickradius = pickradius
    369         self.ind_offset = 0

C:\Users\B4058846\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.pyc in update(self, props)
    854                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
    855                 if func is None or not six.callable(func):
--> 856                     raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
    857                 func(v)
    858             changed = True

AttributeError: Unknown property color_cycle
```

And I am left with a blank 4-pane plot, when there should have been just one with 5 boxplot columns:
[image]

**How to fix this?**

Comment: Works for me using version `0.19.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've verified myself that one needs to have `pandas 0.19.0-1` **together** with `matplotlib 1.5.1-8` to not experience this error.